# How to receive application.properties values in an itemProcessor

Tags: spring, spring-batch

I'm attempting to pass a value from application.properties into a custom ItemProcessor. However, using the @Value annotation always returns null, which isn't entirely unexpected. However, I'm at a loss for how to pass the necessary value in without @Value.

```
@Service
class FinancialRecordItemProcessor implements ItemProcessor<FinancialTransactionRecord, FinancialTransactionRecord> {

Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(FinancialRecordItemProcessor)

// Start Configs

@Value('${base.url:<redacted URL>}')
String baseUrl

@Value('${access.token:null0token}')
String accessToken

// End Configs



@Override
FinancialTransactionRecord process(FinancialTransactionRecord financialRecord) throws IllegalAccessException{

    // Test to ensure valid auth token

    if (accessToken == null || accessToken == "null0token"){
        throw new IllegalAccessException("You must provide an access token. " + accessToken + " is not a valid access token.")
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you using Spring Boot?  Can you provide the configuration itself?  Where is the configuration file located?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a solution. Rather than using @Value on global variables as shown above, they need to be passed into a constructor, i.e.

```
FinancialRecordItemProcessor(String baseUrl, String accessToken){
super()
this.baseUrl = baseUrl
this.accessToken = accessToken
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you defined the `context:property-placeholder` ?!

For example if your configs are at `classpath:/configs`, you need :

```
<context:property-placeholder location="classpath:/configs/*.properties" />
```

Answer (score 0):

You are on the right track. Have a look at `@StepScope`

From official docs:

> Convenient annotation for step scoped beans that defaults the proxy
>   mode, so that it doesn't have to be specified explicitly on every bean
>   definition. Use this on any @Bean that needs to inject @Values from
>   the step context, and any bean that needs to share a lifecycle with a
>   step execution (e.g. an ItemStream). E.g.

Example:

```
   @Bean
   @StepScope
   protected Callable<String> value(@Value("#{stepExecution.stepName}")
   final String value) {
       return new SimpleCallable(value);
   }
```

So basically you can only inject values defined from your step contextbut also can inject values from your job context e.g.

```
@Value(value = "#{jobParameters['yourKey']}")
private String yourProperty;
```

The jobParameters can be set prior to job execution:

```
JobParameters jobParameters = new JobParametersBuilder()
            .addLong("time", System.currentTimeMillis())
            .addString("yourKey", "a value")
            .toJobParameters();

    final JobExecution jobExecution = jobLauncher.run(job, jobParameters);
```